# MySQL Select query not working

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have 2 tables and I want to fetch users data from it.

**Table 1 :** `frei_session`

```
username    session_id

Prince      51
Dilip       49
Sumit       50
```

**Table 2 :** `friendrequest`

```
requestTo   requestFrom     status

49              50              C
50              51              C
49              51              P
```

**friendrequest** table show relationship between users where **C** stands for **Complete** and **P** stands for **Pending**. means if `status = C` both are friends and if `status = P` request is pending.

**frei_session** table display all online users of website.

I want to limit chat with friends only. I have tried following query but it shows all users which are online

suppose user **49** is online

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT f.username,f.session_id
    FROM frei_session AS f
    LEFT JOIN friendrequest AS fr ON fr.requestFrom=f.session_id
    LEFT JOIN friendrequest AS frnd ON frnd.requestTo=f.session_id
    WHERE (fr.requestFrom<>49 OR frnd.requestTo<>49) AND (fr.status = 'C' OR frnd.status = 'C')
```

This query show me output like this

```
username    session_id

Prince          51
Sumit           50
```

but I want output like this

```
username    session_id

Sumit       50
```

because user **51** and user **49** are not friends

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  IF(a.RequestTo = 49, c.userName, b.userName) username,
        IF(a.RequestTo = 49, c.session_ID, b.session_ID) Session_ID
FROM    friendRequest a
        INNER JOIN frei_session b
            ON a.requestTo = b.session_ID
        INNER JOIN frei_session c
            ON a.requestFrom = c.session_ID
WHERE   a.status = 'C' AND
        49 IN (a.requestTo, a.requestFrom)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bb9b/5)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*when all in the `friendrequest` has status of `C`*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdd3d/1)

RESULT

```
╔══════════╦════════════╗
║ USERNAME ║ SESSION_ID ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ Sumit    ║         50 ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ShowAllUserName(IN _sessionID INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT  IF(a.RequestTo = _sessionID, c.userName, b.userName) username,
            IF(a.RequestTo = _sessionID, c.session_ID, b.session_ID) Session_ID
    FROM    friendRequest a
            INNER JOIN frei_session b
                ON a.requestTo = b.session_ID
            INNER JOIN frei_session c
                ON a.requestFrom = c.session_ID
    WHERE   a.status = 'C' AND
            _sessionID IN (a.requestTo, a.requestFrom);
END;
DELIMITER $$
```

when calling the procedure,

```
CALL ShowAllUserName(49);
```

Comment: awesome JW. its working like a charm, you are excellent. thank you very much

Comment: do you want me to convert it into `stored procedure`?

Comment: can you please tell me how can you tabulate your output in that table format?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you join twice the same table ?

try

```
LEFT JOIN friendrequest AS fr ON fr.requestFrom=f.session_id AND fr.requestTo=f.session_id
```

Than, you could change your where query by :

```
WHERE fr.requestFrom<>49 AND fr.status = 'C'
```

I'd try `GROUP BY fr.status` if I did understand your problem, it may work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.username,f.session_id
FROM frei_session AS f
LEFT JOIN friendrequest AS fr ON f.session_id IN (fr.requestFrom, fr.requestTo)
WHERE fr.requestFrom = 49 AND fr.status = 'C'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the users who have received request from Dilip. You then get the users who have sent request to Dilip. After that you union these users. The SQL is something like:

```
SELECT fs.username, fs.session_id
FROM   frei_session AS fs, friendrequest AS fr
WHERE  fs.username = "Dilip"
  AND  fs.session_id = fr.requestFrom
  AND  fr.status = "C"
UNION
SELECT fs.username, fs.session_id
FROM   frei_session AS fs, friendrequest AS fr
WHERE  fs.username = "Dilip"
  AND  fs.session_id = fr.requestTo
  AND  fr.status = "C"
```

I believe that this solution is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  IF(a.RequestTo = 49, c.userName, b.userName) username,
        IF(a.RequestTo = 49, c.session_ID, b.session_ID) Session_ID
FROM    friendRequest a
        INNER JOIN frei_session b
            ON a.requestTo = b.session_ID
        INNER JOIN frei_session c

            ON a.requestFrom = c.session_ID
WHERE   a.status = 'C' AND
        49 IN (a.requestTo, a.requestFrom)
```